# How to Reference the Last Commit on Another Branch

Tags: git

I have two branches, brA and brB.  Every change I make in brA needs to get cherry picked into brB.  My desired workflow runs entirely from the command line and uses as few keystrokes as possible

- Commit work on brA.  Don't memorize the commit id, because I shouldn't have to.  Keystrokes: "`git commit -m`" = 13 + my commit message.
- Check out brB.  Keystrokes: I have `co` aliased to `checkout` and only the two branches so "`git co -`" = 8
- Cherry pick the latest commit from brA to brB.  I have `cp` aliased to `cherry-pick` but I don't know how to reference the last commit on another branch.  Yes, I could just copy and paste the commit id or use a GUI but I'm a developer goddamit and ain't nobody got time for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A branch in git is nothing more but a reference on a commit; each commit has a reference on its parent commit(s) and this is how git builds the history.

When you make a commit on a branch then the reference points to the new commit which has the previous commit as its parent. This effectively means that a branch always points to the "latest" commit.

Obviously it's possible that you reset a branch and "undo" some commits this way, but now the reference points to a different commit so the other commits aren't part of this branch anymore.

This means that you just need to use the reference to get the "latest" commit of a branch which results in the following command:

```
git cherry-pick brA
```

---

**On a sidenote:** A workflow where you need to `cherry-pick` every and each commit from one branch onto another seems kinda off to me and there is probably a better way to achieve whatever you want to do.

**EDIT** I have to correct myself: Of course branches in git aren't symbolic references but just usual references; the only type of symbolic references in git can be found in HEAD. HEAD usually points at a branch and not directly at a commit as branches do.

Comment: I didn't even try `cp brA`! I was too concerned about pulling over the entire branch in some De facto rebase. In retrospect, it's git and I should have just tried it.

Comment: Minor nitpick. "Symbolic references" in Git are [technically distinct from regular branch references](http://jk.gs/git-symbolic-ref.html#_description), though yes, *conceptually*, you can think of both of them as "symbolic pointers" to commits.

Comment: @Cupcake You are right. I'll edit the answer later on, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: In even further retrospect, a `rebase` is **exactly what I want**...D'oh

Answer (score 3):

Other branches' commits can be referenced with the `@` notation as follows:

```
git cp brA@{0}
```

They count backwards from the last commit and are zero-indexed.  I have no idea how it would handle a commit with two parents, but for now, that's not my problem.  That's 11 non-varying characters, "git cp " and "@{0}. This gives me a keystroke total of:

13 + 8 + 11 + commit message + branch name

Comment: While `brA@{0}` will work every time for this, the `@{number}` suffix syntax refers to branch *reflogs*.  In many cases that will in fact correspond to "distance from branch tip", but not all (e.g., after a rebase or reset).  The `~number` form, such as `master~4`, refers to "distance from branch tip", specifically along the first-parent line.  To name the branch tip directly, you can simply use the branch name, with no suffix at all.  (`@{0}` means "the most recent", which is simply where the branch-tip is now, which is why that's guaranteed to be right.)